# Boost Signal References Object Out of Scope?

Tags: c++, boost, signals2

```
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void ()> signal_t;

class AAA {

public:

void Connect(const signal_t::slot_type& subscriber)
{
    return m_sig.connect(subscriber);
}

void FireSignal()
{
    m_sig();
}   

private:

    signal_t sig;
};

// Global
AAA a;

BBB b;

// Some scope
{
...

a.Connect(boost::bind(&BBB:foo, &b));

...
}
```

Now the temporary object returned by previous boost::bind goes out of scope and gets destroyed
However the temporary object is passed to AAA::Connect by reference. 
Now lets say at some point, object a.FireSignal() is called, does the signal calls a function object that's already destroyed??? How does it work otherwise???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a copy of it and keeps it.

The result of your to `boost::bind` is sued to construct a `slot_type` which stores that as a member and then once it is passed to `signal::connect` the signal stores the `slot_type`, which means a copy of your `bind` result is stored within the `signal` and that's the one used and called when the signal fires.

I can't find a place where this is specificaly and axplicitly said but you can more  or less conclude that from:

- [The Slot Class Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/slot.html)
- [The Tutorial Examples Using Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html)
- [The Signal Class Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/signal.html)

Comment: I tried both using pass by reference and object. The boost signals2 crashes! Somehow the signal loses the function object created by bind.

Comment: @Joseph It is more likely that the instance you are using (`BBB b`) died than the bind result itself, additionally there could be other reasons, it really depends on the context.